# Rails 3.1, Unicorn and Apache: static files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, unicorn, static-files

I have Rails 3.1, Unicorn and Apache setup. My Apache settings are below and production.rb looks like [this](http://www.pastie.org/2859132). I like using h264 streaming but since Rails is serving these video files, the Apache Mod won't work.

```
DocumentRoot /blabla/current/public

RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks

<Proxy balancer://unicornservers>
  BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:4000
</Proxy>

# Redirect all non-static requests to rails
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://unicornservers%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

ProxyPass / balancer://unicornservers/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://unicornservers/
ProxyPreserveHost on

<Proxy *>
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
</Proxy>

XSendFile On
XSendFileAllowAbove on
```

I have to enable serve_static_assets or I cannot download any static stuff. I have precompiled assets too but it won't make any difference as no file is available from public directory unless Rails (Rack I guess) is doing the serving.

Should I use config.action_controller.asset_host or is there something wrong with my Apache config.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have a [post](http://tech.manic.tw/2012/02/22/Apache-with-Unicorn.html) for this problem (yeah it also happened to me), hope it will help.

The key point is to remove `ProxyPass / balancer://unicornservers/` pattern, because it would override your `Rewrite Rule`

Here is my apache server config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName example.org
  DocumentRoot /dir/of/your/project

  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirect all non-static requests to unicorn
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://unicornservers%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

  <Proxy balancer://unicornservers>
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:2007
  </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!

btw. Your article link points to localhost.

Comment: perfect, makes complete sense, all the guides i've found for rails 3 + apache + unicon/thin have this problem

Answer (score 0):

Just from your production.rb code:

```
# Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
# config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
# config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx
```

Try to uncomment a line with 'X-Sendfile' header, restart your Unicorn's pool and try again.