# serving static files , apache+ unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, unicorn

I am using rails 3.0.7 and I have apache2 + unicorn installed in the production environment.

I have my `.conf`file as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName something.com

# Point this to your public folder of teambox
DocumentRoot /pal/public

RewriteEngine On

<Proxy balancer://unicornservers>
  BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:5000
</Proxy>

# Redirect all non-static requests to unicorn
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://unicornservers%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

ProxyPass / balancer://unicornservers/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://unicornservers/
ProxyPreserveHost on

<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

Tried `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

But it seems that apache is not serving the static requests ( the files in the public directory). All the static requests also comes to rails. What configuration am I missing ?

Comment: I would put [Nginx](http://nginx.org) instead of Apache. It is much better in handling static.

Comment: Yup aware of that.. but business people..!!! can't help that part

Comment: What about putting nginx in front of apache then? :-)

Comment: can't do that either.. have to make it work just with apache + unicorn . :(

Comment: Nope.. facing the same problem..

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: nope .. I left it with rails serving the static files.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is fairly dated, however...
I was having exactly the same issue, and couldn't find a solution anywhere.
I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116170/rails-3-1-unicorn-and-apache-static-files)

Removing the following works.

```
ProxyPass / balancer://unicornservers/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://unicornservers/
ProxyPreserveHost on
```